# Procedure being created but doesn't work

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, passwords

```
DECLARE 

BEGIN
     FOR  s IN ( SELECT  first_name
                     FROM    EA_marketing_table
              WHERE   town    = 'LONDON'  
            )
     LOOP
           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER ' ||(s.first_name)|| ' IDENTIFIED BY LOL';
           dbms_output.put_line (s.first_name || ' IDENTIFIED BY LOL');
     END LOOP;

END;
/
```

I am trying to create a user and the code above lets me create a user but when I try to create a procedure it wont work.

This is the new code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_it_development AS
first_name VARCHAR2 (25); 

BEGIN
     FOR  r IN ( SELECT  first_name
                 FROM    EA_marketing_table
                 WHERE   town    = 'lONDON ')
     LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER '||(r.first_name)|| ' IDENTIFIED BY POOP ';

     END LOOP;

     EXCEPTION 
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  dbms_output.put_line ('r SELECT...INTO did not return any row.'); 

END;
/
```

any help please?

:)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Passwords are case-sensitive by default from 11g, so make sure you're using exactly the right value. But which password are you using - the one from the anonymous block, or the one from the procedure? Did you drop the users in between running them both? (I was going to ask whether you have `serveroutput` set on when you execute the procedure, so any errors would display; but you cannot get `no_data_found` anyway, and anything else (like user already existing) would cause the proc to abort). What error do you get when you try to log in - ORA-01017, ORA-01045, something else?

Comment: (1) Your new code just creates a procedure - but it doesn't actually *run* it. You need to run it e.g. with `exec proc_it_development;`. (2) you have an exception handler for NO_DATA_FOUND but your procedure will never raise this exception. (3) Make sure you check that there are some rows returned by the query - i.e. is the town really spelled `lONDON`? String comparisons are case-sensitive by default.

Comment: I have tried doing everything, but it still does not allow me to login with the created username and the password,

Comment: SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_market 2 authid current_user as 3 BEGIN 4 FOR a IN ( SELECT first_name FROM EA_marketing WHERE SPECIALISM = 'MARKETING ') 5 LOOP 6 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER'||a.first_name||'IDENTIFIED BY "pass1234" '; 7 END LOOP; 8 END proc_market ; 9 / Procedure created. SQL> EXECUTE proc_market PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Answer (score 0):

[Roles are not enabled in procedures/packages](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551289900368934430) so you need to get the privilege granted to your user directly. Most likely you are connecting through a user that has been given the `CREATE USER` privilege via a role (eg: the DBA role?)

To see what you can do in a procedure, you can disable the active roles for your current session:

```
set role none
```

then try your first code block. If it works, it will also work in a procedure.

To create a new schema with a procedure you will need the privilege granted directly to your schema:

```
GRANT CREATE USER TO <your_schema>;
```

Comment: hi, i have tried doing that but it sill does not work,

Comment: What error message do you get? "Does not work" lacks very much in precision :)

Comment: hi! it doe not give any error message, it says "procedure successfully completed" but whenever we try to log in with the username and the password it doesnt allow us to do so.

Comment: So it does actually work, it just doesn't do what you expect :) Are you sure the `SELECT` returns rows? Why are your procedure and your block not **EXACTLY** the same? Why did you remove the `DBMS_OUTPUT` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose the password in double-quotes, in Oracle 11 passwords are case-sensitive by default. Then you only create a user without any privilege, i.e.CREATE SESSION Privilege is missing.

Comment: You don't have to enclose the password in double quotes. Agree about the session priv though (that's the ORA-01405 reference in my comment *8-), but a user created in the anonymous block shouldn't work either. The procedure vs. block distinction seems to be a red herring. I'd still like the OP to actually say what error they get on login though...

Comment: You don't have to enclose case-sensitive passwords in double-quotes either. (Just double-checked in 11gR2 in case I'm losing the plot. Double-quotes are allowed but make no difference. This isn't an identifier *8-).

Comment: But I assume you get some trouble if the password contains any special character - not only letters.

Comment: when we run the above procedure on ORACLE 10g it says the procedure successfully completed, but we are not allowed to log in with the password and the username. though we are able to log in when we run the anonymous block, also the dbms_output.put_line does not display any results either.  any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the user created? Check view DBA_USERS